# Mercurial hg identifies unchanged files as modified

Tags: version-control, tortoise-hg, hg

I switched to a branch and

```
hg revert --all
```

then I wanted to import a diff file with

```
hg import [filename]
```

However, I got "abort: uncommitted changes". So I typed

```
hg st
```

It turned out that I had several modified files.
But I tried with

```
hg diff -g
```

Only a blank line showed on the command prompt. And both

```
hg revert --all --no-backup
```

and

```
hg up -C -r [revision]
```

are not working. I also tried to delete those files and then revert them, switch to another branch then switch back, but those files are still identified as modified.

Comment: Sometimes diff won't show (or seem to show) apparent changes because they could just be line endings, newlines, etc. If you diff using a graphical tool in "strict" mode (lke Winmerge for instance) it might more clearly show any differences.

Comment: You wrote that `hg revert --all --no-backup` did not work - how did it fail?

Comment: i have the same issue. `hg revert --all --no-backup` doesn't seem to do anything, it lists a bunch of 'reverting ...' files, but if i run it again, it just says the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up in this situation today, too.

I worked around the issue by running `hg update -C null` to empty the working folder, then `hg update [revision]` for the revision I wanted.

Comment: Bless you! This is the only thing that worked and we tried everything!